# Error with math accent in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, greek

I have a problem with the formula:

```
F_q=\frac{Q_1 \cdot Q_2}{\epsilon \cdot 4\pi \cdot r^2}\\
\epsilon = \epsilon_0 + \epsilon_{\text{r}} \\
\epsilon_0 : Elektrische Feldkkonstante\\
\epsilon_r : Dielektrizitätszahl
```

The first `\epsilon_r` prints fine, but the second does not. I get the following error:

> ! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. \accent
>   \epsilon_{\text{r}} : Dielektrizitä

I already tried following without success:

```
\epsilon_{r}
\epsilon_{\text{r}}
```

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: Unrelated: I assume you're using `\text{r}` to get an upright `r` in the subscript. That is the wrong macro to use, use `\mathrm` or similar instead. Her's why: `\textit{text $A_{\text{r}}$ text}` that `r` is now italic because `\text` follows the surrounding text, not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`\text{r}` should be `\mathrm{r}` as it is (I assume part of the math notation and should not pick up the current text font) but conversely `Dielektrizitätszahl` should be

`\text{Dielektrizitätszahl}` or perhaps better `\textrm{Dielektrizitätszahl}`

it is needed for the `ä` (which generates the error) but even without the accent error you probably want a text font for a word, not math italic.

Comment: as an alternative for `\text` for that long word, wouldn't `\textnormal` be better? `\text` might still be italic inside a theorem.

Comment: @daleif yes, or `\textrm` perhaps.

Comment: I think I learned the hardway one day why `\textnormal` was better (consider a situation where some of the text is sans serif, `\textrm` will switch to serif).

Comment: @daleif yes but arguably it's like `\mathrm` the choice of math font shouldn't reflect the document default, you need \text... here for technical reasons on the accent handling but otherwise if you are using \mathrm for `r` why not `\textrm` for thsi?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. The solutions with:

```
\textrm{...}
\textnormal{...}
```

work all, but they change the font and remove the italic style of the text in the math mode.
Someone helped me with a small command:

```
\newcommand{\aumlaut}{\text{\textit{\"a}}}
```

I also created more commands for the `ö` and `ü`, in case I would need them later.